# Adding hidden inputs to the Stripe form to use as post variables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe:

```
<form action="/design/charge" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="DATA KEY"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-name="DATA NAME"
data-description="DATA DESC"
data-amount="{{ $itemPrice }}"
</script>

{{ Form::hidden('canvas-size', 1) }}

</form>
```

Which is working, but I also want to be able to save data about the item the user is buying and process that after the charge is successful.

The form posts to /charge, so as you can see I have added in a hidden input to the form.

For now, I am testing this directly in my route:

```
Route::post('/design/charge', function()
{
  $billing = App::make('Motivate\Billing\BillingInterface');
  $transaction = $billing->charge([
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'token' => Input::get('stripeToken')
  ]);

  $item = new Item;
  $item->canvas_size = Input::get('canvas-size');
  $item->save();
}
```

But the input is blank and not working. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Easy as that! Before the script worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I shall once the timer is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's hidden filed and your script code is comming before it.that is causing problem.

So

Just put your `{{ Form::hidden('canvas-size', 1) }}` code before `script` code and it will work. thanks.

Like this:-

```
<form action="/design/charge" method="POST">
{{ Form::hidden('canvas-size', 1) }}
<script>
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="DATA KEY"
data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-name="DATA NAME"
data-description="DATA DESC"
data-amount="{{ $itemPrice }}"
</script>
</form>
```